# Windows Service Installer - Remove Previous Versions

Tags: windows-services, windows-installer, versioning, upgrade

I have a Windows Service that I am using a Setup Project to create an MSI to install the service.  This works fine for the initial installation of the Windows Service, but when attempting to do subsequent installs (i.e. new version, new MSI) it progresses through the Installation screens, the progress bar gets almost to the end and then I get a message stating

> "Error 1001. The specified service already exists".

Is there a trick to making the installer work for subsequent installations of Windows Services?

In my installer package I have done the following:

- DetectNewerInstalledVersion: True
- Updated ProductCode
- RemovePreviousVersion: True
- Updated Version

Answer (score 2):

before you intall new version of services you must uninstall it and then try.if you use VS to create Windows service using visual studio command promt you can uninstall it easliy.take a google to "uninstall windows service using Insallutill.exe"

Comment: This is definitely what it looks like, do you have a link to a definitive source (Microsoft?).  It looks like it should be able to handle this automatically (i.e. if RemovePreviousVersion: true then it should do uninstall using Installutill.exe automatically or similar)

Comment: LAME. It works and seams to be the only answer. But it's a lame workaround.